# How to add google analytics in ASP.NET websites

Tags: asp.net

How to add google analytics in ASP.NET websites?
And also how to see this reports in ASP.NET webpages.

Comment: What have you tried and in what way is it not working?  Adding Google code snippets to any website, regardless of the server-side technology used, is usually just a matter of copying/pasting code that Google provides for you.

Answer (score 10):

Step by step [from Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1008080);
5 easy steps:

1 - First [create](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1006228&answer=1009694) a google analytics account

---

2- [Add](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1006228&answer=1042508) your site as a web-property to the account you are using.

---

3- In Google Analytics, go to Admin tab > Profiles > Tracking Code

---

4- Create a new javascript file with the code found in the previous step (will look like something like this):

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-Y']); // XXXXX-Y indicates the web property ID for your Analytics account
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

---

5- Finally, include the javascript file to all your asp files OR in your master page if you are using one:

```
<script src="myfolder/JS/GAnalytics.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript" />
```