# How to track no of downloads & location from where the app is downloaded using google analytics api

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Google Analytics: I need to display the following in website using Google Analytics Api:

```
1) No of downloads of the app (android & ios)
2) The location from where the app was downloaded
```

Can somebody please suggest a deep dive link / example with detailed information specific to no of downloads & the location from where it was downloaded from.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Deplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214722/how-to-add-google-analytics-in-asp-net-websites

Comment: http://www.teamscs.com/2014/04/using-google-analytics-in-an-asp-net-mvc-website/

Comment: Naveen thanx for the link, i need to display google analytics on my website for my mobile apps.

Comment: Check the Google Analytics API.  I recommend using the Google-dotnet-client lib. http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Analytics.v3 and use a service account for authentication.

Comment: I also need information like the location from where the app was downloaded from, is that possible?